# Computing $\int_c\vec{\nabla} F \cdot \vec{t}\,ds$, any clever way to eyeball the answer?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, physics

I want to compute the integral$$\int_c \vec{\nabla} F \cdot \vec{t}\,ds,$$where $F = x - y$, $\vec{t}$ is the unit tangent vector, and $c$ is the following "circle" with counterclockwise rotation, i.e. a path along the edges of a square with corners $(1, 1)$, $(-1,1)$, $(-1,-1)$, and $(1,-1)$.

This is a Math GRE practice question, and so I'm wondering what is the quickest way to evaluate this without doing a full setup. How can we eyeball the answer?

Comment: What are $\Delta$ and $\mathbf{t}$?

Comment: I think you mean $\nabla F$ instead of $\Delta F$, and that $\vec t$ is the unit tangent vector. Use Green's Theorem.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I don't see how Green's Theorem applies here.

Comment: Green's theorem is just Stokes Theorem in two dimensions. See this: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/StokesTheorem.aspx. Also, maybe think about what you're doing as you integrate along each edge in terms of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: By the way, what exactly does $\nabla \vec{F}\cdot \vec{t}$ mean?  Does it mean $\nabla\left(\vec{F}\cdot \vec{t}\right)$, or $(\nabla \vec{F})\cdot\vec{t}$?  Both versions make sense (although it is more likely that you mean $\nabla\left(\vec{F}\cdot \vec{t}\right)$).

Comment: @Batominovski Since $F$ is given as a scalar function, he might mean $\vec{\nabla}F\cdot\vec{t}$. Though if that's the case the integral is obviously 0.

Comment: Is the path a square or a circle? Do you mean it's a closed square loop?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: $\nabla F$ is a conservative field. By the [gradient theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem), the closed loop integral is zero.

Evaluating it is quick, though. You ought to practice it, if this looked tough. Just draw a picture. It's quick, since

$$\nabla F = \hat{x} - \hat{y}$$

doesn't depend on $x,y$.

$$\begin{align}
\int_{1 square} \nabla{F}\cdot d\vec{s} &= \int_1^{-1}\nabla{F}\big|_{y=1}\cdot (-\hat{x})dx + \int_1^{-1}\nabla{F}\big|_{x=-1}\cdot (-\hat{y})dy
\\&\quad\quad + \int_{-1}^{1}\nabla{F}\big|_{y=-1}\cdot\hat{x}dx
+ \int_{-1}^{1}\nabla{F}\big|_{x=1}\cdot \hat{y}dx
\\
&= -\int_1^{-1}dx + \int_1^{-1}dy
+ \int_{-1}^{1}dx
- \int_{-1}^{1}dx
\\
&= 2-2+2-2=0
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

The question as it stands does not make any sense:
$$\int_c \vec F\cdot \vec dr=\int_c\vec F\cdot \vec Tds$$
Which, in either, case implies the Function of Force $\vec F$ is a vector function given by: $$\vec F=x\vec i- y\vec j$$ and not by a scalar:$$F=x-y$$

As for the solution of the integral, let us parameterize $x$ and $y$ such that:
$$x=t;0\leq t\leq1$$
$$y=t;0\leq t\leq1$$

Now, notice for any integral: $\int f(u_i)du_i$ $\forall i\in \mathbb N$, and bounds $a\leq u_k\leq b$ for some index $k\in \mathbb N$ $$\int_a^cf(u_i)du_i+\int _c^bf(u_i)du_i=\int_a^b f(u_i)du_i$$

where $a\leq b \leq c$.

Also note, $$\int_{-c}\vec F\cdot \vec Tds=-\int_c\vec F\cdot \vec Tds$$

Given those facts, then integral then becomes:

$$\int_0^1t+\int_0^1t-\int_0^1t-\int_0^1t=0$$

Which, of course, makes sense because the force $\vec F$ is a conservative force since its curl is zero.

Knowing that, always check if the curl of a given force vector is zero. Furthermore, if it is zero, then see if the path is circular. That is, it ends where it began. If it is circular, then the work done is zero, which implies $$\int_c\vec F\cdot \vec Tds=0$$